# reusing answer of previous prompt input

Tags: local-storage, prompt, default-value

I would like to prompt for a symbol and plot stock charts (or weather maps or traffic cams or whatever) such as this example shows:

```html
<script> var sym = "MSFT" </script> 
<script> var syi = prompt("Enter Symbol"); if (syi) { var sym = syi } </script> 

<h1><strong> <body> Symbol <script> document.write(sym); </script></body><br> 

<img src="" id="i1">$_Today <script> var a = document.getElementById('i1'); a.src = "http://www.google.com/finance/chart?cht=o&tlf=12h&q=" + sym ; </script> &nbsp;&nbsp;
<img src="" id="i2">%_Today <script> var a = document.getElementById('i2'); a.src = "http://www.google.com/finance/chart?cht=c&tlf=12h&q=" + sym ; </script> &nbsp;&nbsp;
<!-- etc.  perhaps dozens more different charts for the same symbol -->
```

'

To update to more current charts, say 5 minutes later with a simple "refresh and enter key" I would like to reuse the input from the last prompt  (when null reuse last time a symbol was entered)

Also the first time it runs if no value is given (simply hit enter at prompt) I would like to use a default value, e.g. "MSFT"

How would I code that?

Comment: What language and back-end are you using? You've got to give us more info.

Comment: I just have a .html on my local drive and put the .html file as url: <!Doctype html>   <script>  var sy = "MSFT" </script> 
<script> var syi = prompt("Enter Symbol"); if (syi) { var sy = syi } </script>

<h1><strong> <body> Symbol <script>document.write(sy); </script></body> <br></h1><h2>
   
<img src="" id="i1">$_Today <script> var a = document.getElementById('i1'); a.src = "http://www.google.com/finance/chart?cht=o&tlf=12h&q=" + sy ; </script>

Comment: Please put the code in your answer so it can be properly formatted.

Comment: <!Doctype html>   <script>  var sy = "MSFT" </script> 
<script> var syi = prompt("Enter Symbol"); if (syi) { var sy = syi } </script>

<h1><strong> <body> Symbol <script>document.write(sy); </script></body> <br>
   
<img src="" id="i1">$_Today <script> var a = document.getElementById('i1'); a.src = "http://www.google.com/finance/chart?cht=o&tlf=12h&q=" + sy ; </script><img src="" id="i2">%_Today <script> var a = document.getElementById('i2'); a.src = "http://www.google.com/finance/chart?cht=c&tlf=12h&q=" + sy ; </script>

Answer (score 0):

You can use localstorage if you are not using any user login sessions, if it is a user session you can use server sider sessions.

```
var myStorage = window.localStorage;  
var value = localStorage.getItem("myValue")||"MSFT";
```

// draw chart with value

more details on localstorage is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Thank you very much.  I tried, but guess I know too little to getting it working right.  I posted a complete running version above, except it always reverts to MSFT of course if I enter NO new value.